# Extracting values from a df

Tags: python, pandas

Problem statement:

There are multiple instances of charging and discharging for each vehicle, get the minimum charge, maximum charge, min discharge and max discharge for each vehicle for a particular day.

df1

```
Date             Time    vehicle_no  soc     SOC Diff
0   2022-10-01  02:27:56    DL21GD0100  80.0    0
1   2022-10-01  02:28:26    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
2   2022-10-01  02:28:56    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
3   2022-10-01  02:29:26    DL21GD0100  80.0    Discharging
4   2022-10-01  02:29:56    DL21GD0100  69.0    Discharging
5    2022-10-01 02:29:56    DL21GD0100  70.0    Charging
6    2022-10-01 02:29:56    DL21GD0100  71.0    Charging
7    2022-10-01 02:29:56    DL21GD0100  72.0    Charging
8   2022-10-01 03:16:00    DL21GD0100   63.0    Discharging
9  2022-10-01  03:16:30    DL21GD0100    23.0    Discharging
10  2022-10-01  04:17:00    DL21GD0100    54.0    Charging
11  2022-10-01  09:17:30    WB25M9298   24.0    Charging
12  2022-10-01  09:18:00    WB25M9298   25.0    Charging
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole answer for 3 different options

##### mapping strictly charge/discharge

You can use [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) to get the difference per group, then [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['status'] = np.sign(df.groupby('vehicle_no')['soc'].diff()
                       ).map({1: 'Charging', -1: 'Discharging'})
```

Or with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
s = df.groupby('vehicle_no')['soc'].diff()

df['status'] = np.select([s>0, s<0], ['Charging', 'Discharging'], np.nan)
```

Output:

```
          Date      Time  vehicle_no   soc       status
0   2022-10-01  02:27:56  DL21GD0100  80.0          NaN
2   2022-10-01  02:28:56  DL21GD0100  80.0          NaN
3   2022-10-01  02:29:26  DL21GD0100  80.0          NaN
4   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  69.0  Discharging
5   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  70.0     Charging
6   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  71.0     Charging
7   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  72.0     Charging
8   2022-10-01  09:16:00   WB25M9298  23.0          NaN
9   2022-10-01  09:16:30   WB25M9298  23.0          NaN
10  2022-10-01  09:17:00   WB25M9298  24.0     Charging
11  2022-10-01  09:17:30   WB25M9298  24.0          NaN
12  2022-10-01  09:18:00   WB25M9298  25.0     Charging
```

##### mapping Charge/Discharge with steady as Discharge

If you want to consider equal value as Discharging:

```
df['status'] = np.where(df.groupby('vehicle_no')['soc'].diff().gt(0), 'Charging', 'Discharging')
```

Output:

```
          Date      Time  vehicle_no   soc       status
0   2022-10-01  02:27:56  DL21GD0100  80.0  Discharging
2   2022-10-01  02:28:56  DL21GD0100  80.0  Discharging
3   2022-10-01  02:29:26  DL21GD0100  80.0  Discharging
4   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  69.0  Discharging
5   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  70.0     Charging
6   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  71.0     Charging
7   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  72.0     Charging
8   2022-10-01  09:16:00   WB25M9298  23.0  Discharging
9   2022-10-01  09:16:30   WB25M9298  23.0  Discharging
10  2022-10-01  09:17:00   WB25M9298  24.0     Charging
11  2022-10-01  09:17:30   WB25M9298  24.0  Discharging
12  2022-10-01  09:18:00   WB25M9298  25.0     Charging
```

##### mapping Charge/Discharge with steady as previous state:

```
d = {1: 'Charging', -1: 'Discharging'}
df['status'] = (df.groupby('vehicle_no')['soc']
                .transform(lambda s: np.sign(s.diff()).map(d).ffill())
                .fillna('Discharging')
               )
```

Output:

```
          Date      Time  vehicle_no   soc       status
0   2022-10-01  02:27:56  DL21GD0100  80.0  Discharging
2   2022-10-01  02:28:56  DL21GD0100  80.0  Discharging
3   2022-10-01  02:29:26  DL21GD0100  80.0  Discharging
4   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  69.0  Discharging
5   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  70.0     Charging
6   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  71.0     Charging
7   2022-10-01  02:29:56  DL21GD0100  72.0     Charging
8   2022-10-01  09:16:00   WB25M9298  23.0  Discharging
9   2022-10-01  09:16:30   WB25M9298  23.0  Discharging
10  2022-10-01  09:17:00   WB25M9298  24.0     Charging
11  2022-10-01  09:17:30   WB25M9298  24.0     Charging
12  2022-10-01  09:18:00   WB25M9298  25.0     Charging
```

Comment: How to fetch min Soc and Max soc (charging and discharging values) each vehicle to a separate column.

Comment: `df['min_soc'] = df.groupby('vehicle_no')['soc'].transform('min')`, same with `'max'`

Comment: This helped similarly I have identified min and max time df2['Min_time']=df2.groupby('vehicle_no')['Time'].transform('min'). But there are multiple instances of charge and discharge for each vehicle. Have to seperate df for charging data.

Comment: What about your initial question? Did my code work for you?

Comment: Yes,This helped similarly I have identified min and max time df2['Min_time']=df2.groupby('vehicle_no')['Time'].transform('min'). But there are multiple instances of charge and discharge for each vehicle. Have to get seperate df for charging data. Note all the charge instances' min and max SOC and respective time duration and calculate average  time and average SOC/Day

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
df1.groupby(['vehicle_no','status']).agg({'soc':[min,max]})
```